# how we get the answer in matrix form in here without drawing transition diagram?

Tags: markov-chains

Three white and three black balls are distributed in two urns in such a way that each contains three balls.

By saying that the system is in state i, i = 0,1,2,3, if the first urn contains i white balls. At each step, we draw one ball from each urn and place the ball drawn from the first urn into the second, and conversely with the ball from the second urn.

Xn denote the state of the system after the nth step.

how we get the answer in matrix form in here without drawing transition diagram?? Is it necessary to draw it?? But following is hard to understand that having many letters denote by bla bla..Can any one explain what is going on??

I can get the matrix answer using a transition diagram..But I can't understand how to draw it for a scenario..If it is given each states [i={0,1,2,3}] having some values filling by 1 each raw, then I can draw it. But here it is hard to understand what is denote by Xn, Yn and Zn..

```
P(Yn = 1|Xn = 0) = 0              P(Zn = 1|Xn = 0) = 1
P(Yn = 1|Xn = 1) = 1/3            P(Zn = 1|Xn = 1) = 2/3
P(Yn = 1|Xn = 2) = 2/3            P(Zn = 1|Xn = 2) = 1/3 
P(Yn = 1|Xn = 3) = 1              P(Zn = 1|Xn = 3) = 0



to get the answer in matrix form




P = | 0    1    0    0 |
    |1/9  4/9  4/9   0 |
    |0   4/9  4/9  1/9 |
    |0    0    1    0  |
```

Actually I can't understand what is happening here with Xn ,Yn and Zn. Isn't it easy to get the answer with a transition diagram?